# MySQL Columns default value is the default value from primary key of another table

Tags: sql, mysql

(Table)File has many (Table)Words

FK Words.file_id related to a single File.id

Default value of Words.frame is equal to File.frame for that PK/FK

Does this type of default relationship have a name? Examples on getting this setup? (MySQL)

Edit

---

The reason for this is that words may have the same frame as the file and if they do, we want to use that default, however some may not and need to be set manually. Is this really bad practice to handle it this way as described in one of the answers? Any improvement suggestions?

Comment: If the frame of the file changes, should the frames of the words that are still using the default also change, or should they stay with what the default was when they were added?  That's the question I would ask to determine whether this is data duplication.  (If the word frame should change to match, then that should be represented with a null value rather than copying.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to [use a Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html). You should be able to mimick the "default value" of `Words.frame` to be based on the value of another field from the `File` table.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a name, but feels like denormalization / data duplication to me.

@Daniel Vassallo suggests an insert trigger for this, and I think that would be the best approach as well if this is really what you need.